# Android, JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

In my Android app, I'm trying to communicate with a web server that holds randomly-generated fake usernames and scores.

```
{ scores: [
 {
un: "Feltricapulta",
sc: "143"
},
{
un: "Henroid",
sc: "120"
},
{
un: "ieteubmospta",
sc: "70"
},
{
un: "pmbotesteuai",
sc: "67"
},
{
un: "epesomiubtat",
sc: "65"
}
] }
```

The code in the PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php 

    include ('connecttomysql.php');


    $command = 'SELECT un, sc FROM xmlscores ORDER BY sc DESC';
    $execute_command = mysql_query($command);

        echo '{ "scores": ';

    while ($table_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute_command))
        {
            $jsonArray [] = $table_row;         
        }
        echo json_encode($jsonArray);

        echo '}'

    ?>
```

I've called this `.php` URL in Android using the generic `HttpGet` method. The output of the json data prints to the stacktrace and provides me with the "Cannot convert from Object to Array" error.

Looking at the PHP file and the json output, is there anything noticeably wrong with my codes or the output? I can't figure it out.

Comment: What's your Android code?  You probably have a .getJSONArray() where you need a .getJSONObject().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Cannot convert from Object to Array"

means you are trying to convert response string to `JSONArray`. but Current String Contains `JSONObject` as root element instead of `JSONArray`. so convert it to `JSONObject` as:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(<Server response string here>);

//  get scores JSONArray from json
JSONArray jsonscoresarray=json.getJSONArray("scores");
...
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue xD I was passing the Entity response String into a new jsonArray. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

// Implementation of Json array should go like this.

```
 @Override
    public void fromJSON(Object json) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject((String) json);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("scores");
        mScores = new ArrayList<Score>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObjct = (JSONObject)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Score object = new Score();
            object.fromJSON(jsonObjct);
            mScores.add(object);
            }
        }
```